# Bash: How can i remove characters from a string until i hit a specific character

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, variable, string

Basically, I'm trying to make a program that at one point needs to store coordinates. There is one part of the program where I need to separate one string into two so I an able to preform math on the two strings separately, then reattach the two strings. An example of how strings would need to be changed in a kind of pseudocode:

```
Var1="10 17"
separate Var1 into Var2 and Var3
#using the command echo "$Var1,Var2,Var3" here would output 10 17,10,17
#preform math on Var2 and/or Var3 here
Var1="$Var2 $Var3"
```

Part of the problem is that I can't just do

```
Var2=${Var1::-2}
```

or whatever the equivalent is for removing the first characters to remove the first or last two digits because these numbers could sometimes be more than 99 or less than 10. Note that I would like for the separator between the two numbers to be a space. Does anybody know how I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the separator is a single space, use [prefix and suffix stripping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
before_the_first_space="${Var1%% *}"
after_the_first_space="${Var1# *}"
before_the_last_space="${Var1%* }"
after_the_last_space="${Var1##* }"
```

Alternatively, take advantage of [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting) on unquoted variable substitutions. This treats each whitespace sequence as a separator and puts the result into an array. [`set -f`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin) disables [wildcard expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion), `set +f` turns it back on.

```
set -f
parts=($Var1)
set +f
echo "${parts[0]}"
```

Alternatively, use the [`read` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) to split the variable into an array. `read` reads from standard input, so use a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) to pass the content of the variable as input.

```
read -r -a parts <<<"$Var1"
```

Both the unquoted-substitution method and the `read` method split based on the value of [`IFS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting).